# Redirect to (currenturl)/example.html onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have my location change from 'currentUrl' to 'currentUrl/somePage.html' when you click a button.

It's important that the code isn't reliant on having a hard-coded url. Instead, it should grab the current url that the user is sitting at and append the value of '/somePage.html' to the end of it.

I've done some looking and found that window.location.href will return my current url location, and that window.location will redirect me to a new one. However, when I try putting these together, I'm getting a "function not defined" error when I click my buttons.

My code looks something like this...

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="redirectToPage()">Some Page</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    function redirectToPage() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        window.location(url + "/somePage.html");
    }
});
```

You're all beautiful people! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery then you should use all of it's capabilities:

(that and I would never recommend inline javascript)

html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default js-do-redirect">Some Page</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-do-redirect').on('click', function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.location = url + "/somePage.html";
  });
});
```

or if you want to make it reusable:

html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default js-do-redirect" data-redirect-to="/somePage.html">
  Some Page
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-do-redirect').on('click', function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var page = $(this).data('redirect-to');
    window.location = url + page;
  });
});
```

Recommended reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're close. window.location is not a function, but a propery.

```
function redirectToPage() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    window.location = url + "/somePage.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirectToPage` is only defined within the handler function's scope. You need to move it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is scoping.
Either remove the `$(function(){})` jQuery closure or use jQuery to create the onClick event on the button with  [$('#someid').click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/).